# What do Greek Mathematicians use when they use our equivalent Greek letters in formulas and equations?

Tags: notation, math-history

Like for example, it's common to use the Greek letter $\theta$ to represent an angle right? So what would a Greek person doing math use to represent an angle? Would they also use $\theta$? Or is there another notation that they would use in order for them to use their letters like we do? Such as if we say $A\geq B$, would a Greek student, mathematician, or whoever say: $\alpha \geq \beta$ or is there something else they say? It just seems like the Greek letters from a non-Greek point of view have so much meaning to us, but then how do they percieve their letters used in mathematics?

Comment: What do we use to denote slope of a straight line? Well, either the letter $\,a\,$ or $\,m\,$...I guess greek students use more or less the same letters as we do, but perhaps there's someone from Greece around to disipate any doubt.

Comment: Nice question - I've wondered about that myself.

Comment: I just know about Russian books: They write the formulas in latin style and the rest in cyrillic. So my guess is that mathematical formula are more or less universal (as are numbers).

Comment: @Fabian i like your answer, I looked up on google Cyrillic and I found where the notation commonly used for partial derivatives comes from.

Comment: By the way, A and B are Greek letters too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Greeks seems to use the Latin letters together with Greek letters as the rest of us. Here is a screen dump from some notes on [Functional analysis](http://users.uoa.gr/~apgiannop/fa.pdf). Of course this is just an example.
[image]

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for that. I never thought about the fact that latin letters are pretty much the same as English letters. I will accept this as an answer that makes sense to me, but I will leave it up to anyone to believe what they believe is right

Comment: There is no choice anyway, mathematicians often need a lot of symbols, so they use all the letters of both alphabets, and then other symbols when it is finished ^^

Answer (score 14):

I am Greek.
We use all the letters, Greek or Latin. But we pronounce some of them in a different way.
For example the letter $\mu$ is pronounced "me". The letter $\beta$ as "vita". The angles are almost always named as $\theta, \phi, \omega$.
If somebody writes $A\ge B$ we read the same as $\alpha\ge \beta$.
The only problem is when you want a student to understand that $\chi \psi$ denotes $\chi\cdot \psi$ but $\ln a$ has nothing to do with $l\cdot n \cdot a$.
Finally, I wanted to add that actually $\pi$ is not pronounced like the food - for example (apple-**pie**) - but like "me" with the letter p at the beginning (that is, "pe").

Comment: That might cause some giggles in elementary schools here on $\pi$-Day (March 14) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience with Greeks, they set $a = \alpha$ and $b=\beta$ etc... however, the Greeks I knew were beyond associating a concept with a letter, so perhaps these are not the Greeks which you seek.

I do recall many conversations of the form: "is it "a" or is it "$\alpha$"" to which I would inevitably get the annoyed retort: "yes".

Answer (score 3):

They also use the same (Greek) letters. For example, for angles, it is very common to use $\phi$ or $\theta$ and in equations, they use $\chi$ and $\psi$. Similarly, they use the Greek alphabet (capital letters) Α, Β, $\Gamma$, $\Delta$, etc., for points in Geometry, etc cetera.